# how do I get an alert if our upload bandwidth used crosses a threshold?

Tags: network, utilities

I need an alert when someone on our home network LAN is doing too much uploading. This is just one wifi router for a small home network.

I could keep an app running on one Mac (running Sierra) that would oversee this and ideally when upload bandwidth crosses a threshold of Mbps:

1. throttle upload
2. pop up alert on the mac
3. send an email alert

Is there a tool that could do this?

Comment: We need a lot more information about your LAN, and especially information about who or what monitors this threshold. Does anything happen to the bandwidth when this threshold is reached tike throughput throttling?

Comment: @IconDaemon updated to clarify - thanks for the request

Answer (score 2):

You want an edge router to shape the traffic, set quality of service and optionally have alarms. These are extremely reasonably priced for the features they allow.

- [https://www.amazon.com/Ubiquiti-Networks-ER-X-Router/dp/B0144R449W/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0144R449W)

Some of the alerting won't be needed since you can shape the actual traffic rather than go react to it.

Comment: [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) also has this capability and is available as a ready-to-deploy (paid) solution or as an open source (free) download you install on a cheap PC ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0JFfpG4BWI))